# partially overlapping figures

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

How do I put two figures next to each other (in one row) while figure 1 overlap (partially) figure 2? I have seen some other questions however I want no space between figures and part of a figure overlap other figure.

Comment: We have a lot of questions exactly preventing such an overlapping, perhaps you should look at them to get what they have done wrong ;-)

Comment: have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes especially `\parbox`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Murphy's law: When required Errors are difficult to reproduce!

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 6):

It depends a lot on the type of overlapping you want. A simple way is negative space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\hspace*{4cm}\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-A}\hspace{-8cm}\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In tikzpicture you can naturally do also overlaps.